# Is trackHistory available for standard object fields

Tags: field-history

Is there a API to check if trackHistory is enabled on opportunity fields. The documentation says its available for standard object fields (picklist and lookup fields only) in API version 30.0 and later.

If not is there a way to check for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifically talking about the Opportunity fields, the salesforce object that you would be interested in is OpportunityHistory. I know the latest version of the API will allow you to describe the history. In which, you should be able to see all of the Fields that are part of this object.

REST API URL:
/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/OpportunityHistory/describe

There should be an equivalent describe call for Soap as well if you are using the soap api.

Comment: Would querying OpportunityHistory tell me if history tracking is enabled on opportunity ?

Comment: Unfortunately it will not, and I do not recall there being anything in the API documentation that exposes whether or not track history field itself is turned on for an object. In the meanwhile, you could create a custom object that could help track whether or not tracking is enabled. By dynamically populating your custom object with the  sObjects and then have a scheduled trigger run to determine if the History is enabled by updating specific records and seeing if the count of your history objects changed. Might be a little overhead but could get the job done.